# Cannot read property 'object.property' of undefined Angular 10

Tags: angular

I have trouble understanding how Angular fills an object coming from an observable, because when I declare an array, the objects of the array and their properties are filled automatically and they are readable in the template. However, when there is only one object to read in the template, I can't read the properties of the object, even if I'm able to fill the object and see the result with a `console.log()`.

So how should I call my object to read its properties in the template?

I did try with an Interface but the result is the same.

Here is my code:

```js
export class DataTable {
  idSite!: number;
  idenseigne!: number;
  siteName!: string;
  enseigneName!: string;
}
export class FicheSiteComponent implements OnInit {

  idSite!: number;

  siteInfo: DataTable = new DataTable();

  constructor(private dataTableService : DataTableService
              , private route : ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))

    this.LoadInfo(id)
  }

  LoadInfo(id : number){
    this.dataTableService.fetchSiteById(id).subscribe(r => {
      this.siteInfo = r
      console.log(this.siteInfo)
    });
  }
}
```

here the template

```html
<div  class="head" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch">
  <div class="site">

    <h1>{{siteInfo.siteName}}</h1>
    <div class="headTitle">
      <h2>{{siteInfo.enseigneName}}</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

result from my request in the observable which I can see in the console.log()

```json
}
enseigneName: "3W"
idEnseigne: 1
idSite: 1
siteName: "3W The siteName"
}
```

Comment: Try adding the safety operator to your template bindings. `{{siteInfo?.siteName}}` & `{{siteInfo?.enseigneName}}`. If your service is async the template will be querying the value before it exists.

Comment: I did but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use interfaces:

```
export interface DataTable {
  idSite: number;
  idenseigne: number;
}
```

now in your ts file:

```
siteInfo: DataTable;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?